# How to create polymorphic association through form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails application I have a polymorphic association set up like this:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoiceable, polymorphic: true
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, as: :invoiceable
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, as: :invoiceable
end
```

My users should be able to choose if a new invoice is associated with a person or a company. How can this be done?

I figured that it must be something like this:

```
<%= f.select :invoiceable, current_user.people.options + current_user.companies.options %>
```

This populates the form correctly but it doesn't save to the `invoiceable_id` and `invoiceable_type` database fields when a user saves the invoice.

This is my InvoicesController action:

```
def create
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(invoice_params)
  if @invoice.save
    flash[:success] = "Invoice saved."
    redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can try to put a `binding.pry` (add the gem `pry` if you don't have it) just after the `@invoice = ...` line. Then watch what are in your invoice_params, and do what you have to do to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I ended up doing something [like this](https://neanderslob.com/2015/11/03/polymorphic-associations-the-smart-way-using-global-ids/). [This](http://stefan.haflidason.com/simpler-polymorphic-selects-in-rails-4-with-global-id/) was also quite helpful.